# StorageFolder GetOrCreate

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp

I am creating a method that either gets or creates and returns a StorageFolder my current code is this

```
    public static IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder> GetOrCreateFolderAsync ( this StorageFolder folder, string folderName )
    {

        try
        {

            return folder.GetFolderAsync ( folderName );

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return folder.CreateFolderAsync ( folderName );

        }

    }
```

it is not throwing an error in the compiler but at runtime it's crashing. Is there something I'm missing I'm new to threading an asynchronous programming so I have no idea what I'm missing or doing incorrectly.

EDIT: To clarify the intention is that I would call the method this way

```
public async StorageFolder foo(StorageFolder parent, string child)
{
    return await parent.GetOrCreateFolderAsync(child);
}
```

Comment: You aren't awaiting the operation. The exception is raised on the await. Instead you are just returning the operation, and the caller will be the one that awaits it (and it is at that point that the exception is raised).

Comment: @RaymondChen To clarify both GetFolderAsync and CreateFolderAsync return IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder> I call await in the method that calls this extension

Comment: @RWolfe, like @Raymond Chen said the exception is raised on the await. In my testing, if I'm trying to get a folder that does not exist in the folder, the `GetOrCreateFolderAsync ` will return the `IAsyncOperation` object which doesn't complete its task, so it won't throw the exception. But in the place you called `GetOrCreateFolderAsync` method, you got the `IAsyncOperation` object as returned result and await it to finish, then it will throw an exception for file not found. That's why the try/catch block doesn't work because returning the `IAsyncOperation` object won't cause issues.

Comment: So how can I make it check if the file exists and go from there?

Comment: Like we've been saying: Use `await`. `try { return await folder.GetFolderAsync(folderName); } catch (Exception) { return await folder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName); }`

Comment: @RaymondChen would my method then just return the folder?

Comment: @RWolfe not exactly. After using await, `GetOrCreateFolderAsync ` method should return a `Task<StorageFolder>` object.